# How do you scrape tag with slightly different class name in each loop with soup?

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, classname

```html
<p class="result"><span class="bold">Final result </span><strong>107:74</strong> (22:16, 26:16, 31:24, 28:18)</p>
```

For the above tag I first was on loop collecting final results using the following code:

```py
final_result = soup.find('p', class_='result')
```

Which worked fine. But when I try to get the date from the p tag below using similar code I repeatedly get None returned. Each class name has slightly different digits in the middle of the t number after date datet, so I tried to use just date in the soup.find class_, but nothing I tried has worked.

```html
<p class="date datet t1594281600-4-1-1-1">Today, 09 Jul  2020, 09:00</p>
```

Full example of html can be found here:
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/china/cba/zhejiang-chouzhou-sichuan-tKo8L67d/

Answer (score 0):

It will be complex using the `class_` attribute.

You can try the `select` method instead like below:

`soup.select('p.date')`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that the tag containing the date is populated after the page is loaded. However, the information is contained int the `class` attribute and store as epoch time (`1594281600` is equivalent to `Thursday 9 July 2020 08:00:00` in GMT timezone).

Here is how you could handle it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/china/cba/zhejiang-chouzhou-sichuan-tKo8L67d/', headers=headers)

tag_date = soup.find('p',{'class':'datet'})
# Extract the class name and get the attribute that contains the epoch time
epoch_time = tag_date.get('class')[-1].split('-')[0].replace('t','')
converted_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(epoch_time)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(converted_time)
```

**Output**:

> '2020-07-09 10:00:00'

There seem to be a timezone parameter you might have to handle but the general idea is here.